# Synchronous execution between methods and listener in java

Tags: java, listener, synchronous, jssc

Assuming i have to write 10 times consecutively to a serial port.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
     serialPort.writeInt(i);
// wait until SerialPortEventListener receives something then write again
    }
```

or:

```
void writeMoreDate(){
         serialPort.writeInt(something);
    // wait until SerialPortEventListener receives something then write again
         serialPort.writeInt(something;
    // wait until SerialPortEventListener receives something then write again
         serialPort.writeInt(something);
}
```

And i have a Serial Port Event Listener, that fires every time i write something to it, and calls **.map()** method.

```
 @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        if (event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {

 //when data arrived do something and notify that next method can execute!            
        } 
    }
```

How can i make method to wait until serialEvent receives something?

-This is how i handled this until now using ***java.util.concurrent.Semaphore***:

ex:

```
  Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_CONCURRENT_THREADS, true);

        void writeMoreDate(){
           Runnable runnable () -> { 
             serialPort.writeInt(something);
             semaphore.acquire();
             serialPort.writeInt(something;
             semaphore.acquire();
             serialPort.writeInt(something);
             semaphore.acquire();
            }
               new Thread(runnable).start();
           }
```

and on Serial Listener:

```
 @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        if (event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {
               semaphore.release();
        } 
    }
```

But I'm not sure if that is right solution. Thanks.

Comment: Normally, if you want to wait until you've received some data, you wouldn't use a for loop. Rather, you'd do your write call in the listener on notification.

Comment: I need to write an flash ISO image to serial port writing 128 bytes per time, in a for loop. After each write, listener confirms that everything was fine, and this is the flag to send another 128 bytes. That's why i need this in a for loop.

Comment: So read until you've got 128 bytes and then write that chunk. Why is that a problem?

Comment: Could you maybe just use two threads for it? one writing, another one waiting to read data and then use a blocking call on the serial port?

Comment: ControlAltDel 
I suppose my question is a little confusing, ore u don't get it, sorry about that. I'll try to explain again. 
My communication with serial port must be Synchronous, there must be a question from me, and a answer from serial port.And i can't ask second question while i didn't receive previous answer.  With just one question everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try doing it a bit more recursively instead of using a for loop. Something along the lines of:

```
private int activeIndex = -1;
private int maxIndex = -1;

private void write(int currentIndex, int maxIndex){
    if(maxIndex < currentIndex)
        return;

    activeIndex = currentIndex;
    maxIndex = maxIndex;

    serialPort.writeInt(currentIndex);
}
```

And then in your event listener you would trigger the next write event after the last event has finished...

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    if (event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {
        .....

        write(activeIndex + 1, maxIndex);
    } 
}
```

It would be much cleaner if you could somehow pass the current/max indices through the SerialPortEvent instead of using class variables to hold the data, but I'm not familiar enough with those classes to know if that's possible.

So, from your example, you could use it with:

```
write(0, 10);
```

Comment: I've edited question, my bad with explanation, take a look if you can. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think my solution still applies to your question. It will recursively wait until the serialEvent(SerialPortEvent) has been triggered before writing the next, which is synchronous